Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3d1b2c66 error in android studio
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3d1b2c66 this error is shown in android studio
i was tring to run texttospeech app on android and at that time of running the app "Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3d1b2c66" this error was coming in adnroid studio.please help me with the required solution related to this error. i have tried every possible options from my side
